Components Panel - View source for this element disabled for NextJS
I used "create-next-app@latest" and selected TypeScript, src/ directory, to create a new project.
from package.json
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "next": "14.2.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^5",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.2.7"
  }

I'm trying to use the React Developer Tools chrome extension, Components panel to debug the application but the "View source for this element" is disabled when I focus on a component I wrote.
I expected the button to be enabled.
How do I enable the "View source..." button on the Component in React Developer Tools, Component panel in Chrome Developer Tools?
